# How to run 'pub build' programmatically?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Short (and maybe simple) question: Is it possible, to call `pub build` programmatically via a dart script?

For now, I'm using: `Process.run('pub', ['build'], runInShell: true);`. 
Is there are more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [barback](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barback) package on pub. The docs are available [here](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/barback).

Comment: Hmm your comment disappeared? I'll answer anyway. I know this is a just a minimal answer - I haven't used this before so I can't give you any more details. I'd suggest posting to the dart mailing list http://dartlang.org/mailing-list . The author of pub is quite active there. If you figure out how to do it, answer your own question here. I'm curious to know more.